# OAuth 2.0 is required for using google picker?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, google-api, oauth-2.0, google-drive-api

In my chrome extension, I want to upload files to google drive by using the google dirve UI, or specifically the google picker. I wonder if this requires OAuth 2.0, or I can simply use the  API key. I have checked the documents but didn't find the answer.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, as of 15th Jan 2014. See https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-picker-api/gN98MUGl4Jg